# changing referent of const std::string reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I'm playing around with references in C++, and noted a bit of odd behavior that I am unable to explain. My understanding is that if I have a non-const variable and a const reference to that same variable and then modify the non-const variable, the reference should reflect that modification.

Example:

```
void foo() {
    int x = 5;
    const int& y = x;
    x = 10;
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y = " << y << std::endl;
}
```

produces the following output for me:

```
x = 10
y = 10
```

However, if I change the type to std::string, the const reference doesn't seem to reflect the modified variable:

```
void foo() {
    std::string x = "abc";
    const std::string& y = x;
    x = "xyz";
    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y = " << y << std::endl;
}
```

produces the following for me:

```
x = xyz
y = abc
```

Is this the normal expected behavior when attempting this with std::string? (I'm using GCC 4.6.0; I don't have any other compiler available at the moment, so I don't know if this is only happening with this specific version or not.)

Comment: That code compiled with *g++-mp-4.6 (GCC) 4.6.0 20100814* prints `xyz` twice, I have tried in different optimization levels. Have you *copied* the exact code?

Comment: Works as expected for me. ("xyz\nxyz\n"). This leads me to believe there is either a BCAK bug or a copy and paste bug. Please check your code and post the full compilable version of the code (**using copy and paste**).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the information. I did get it to work the way I was expecting by copy-pasting to another file. When I viewed the original in binary mode, there were a lot of extraneous bytes hidden before the "&" in my declaration that I can only guess was somehow causing the trouble. I don't know how it even compiled like that. But thanks everyone for helping me with this. You all are awesome!

Answer (score 10):

Works totally fine and just as expected for me [with GCC 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/pZU2C) and [4.5.1](http://ideone.com/Hx3wN) aswell as offline with MSVC 10. You are not showing us the code you execute it seems, or there is a bug in 4.6.0 which I don't believe. Are you sure you're actually using a reference and not just a `const std::string` in your real code?

Comment: The only portion of my code I didn't show was the header-file includes, the declaration of foo() before main(), and main() which simply called foo() and returned 0 to the system. I rewrote this in another file, and it's behaving the way I was expecting now (i.e., y = xyz), so I guess something is just screwy in the original code?

Comment: @Bobby: There is probably some unintended difference that you have not realized. Try performing a diff of the two files and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Check the source file with some other program, you might have saved it accidentally without the &, or some kind of encoding issue. Frankly, I doubt an error of this size would ever exist in GCC. In fact, I doubt if this behavior would be even possible.

Works as expected here with the following config:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.5.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgomp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-werror --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.5.2 (GCC)
```